# Shell script to read file line by line and find value greater than 1000 and print

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have a file which contains data as below:

```
SYSTEM: Running, Fri Jan  6 00:00:01 GMT 2017

    29 DEADLETTER
   123 SU
  1234 SR
  100089 SM
  1278969 DR
```

From this file, I want to read each line and find the value which is greater than 1000 and if its greater than 1000 execute 1 set of command, if its less than 1000 execute another set of commands.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes you can extract the numeric part with regular expressions

Comment: This is the sample file, i have more than 1000 lines, so how can i read each line and check for value more than 1000. I understand with while/for loop i can read line. But not sure with regex. Is possible for you to help?

Answer (score 0):

Let me share one way of doing this (I believe someone can share a better one)
You need to remove/skip the first line of file to make this work.

```
while read line
do 
    num=`echo $line | cut -d " " -f1`
    if (( $num > 1000)); 
    then 
       "Your if logic"
    else
       "Your else logic"
    fi ; 
done< filename
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `awk` like this:

```
awk 'NR<3{next} $1<1000 {system("echo 1")} $1>1000{system("echo 2")}' file
```

**Output**

```
1
1
2
2
2
```

That says... *"If the line number is less than 3, forget it and move to the next line. If the first field is less than 1000, run the command `echo 1`. If the first field is more than 1000, run the command `echo 2`"*.

Note that your question doesn't deal with the number being exactly 1000, so nor does my answer - but you could use `$1<=1000` if you wanted to make it deal with 1000.

---

If you really wanted to only use `bash` shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
{ read header
  read header
  while read f1 f2; do
    [ $f1 -lt 1000 ] && echo 1
    [ $f1 -gt 1000 ] && echo 2
  done } < file
```

The `{...}` is a compound statement that reads from `file`. Inside there, I read and discard two header lines then enter a loop reading subsequent lines into 2 separate fields, `f1` and `f2`. I then check the value of `f1` and execute a different `echo` depending on whether the field is less than, or more than 1000.

Same deal as above with first field being exactly 1000 - you can use `-le` for *"less than or equal"* and `-ge` for *"greater than or equal"*.

---

Or you could use `sed` to get rid of the 2 header lines like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed '1,2d' file | while read f1 f2; do
    [ $f1 -lt 1000 ] && echo 1
    [ $f1 -gt 1000 ] && echo 2
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.

```
cat yourfile.txt | awk -F " " '{if ($1<THRESHOLD) print $1;else print $2}' > result.txt
```

Explain: **-F** option: separate each line by space " "
Example:

```
 cat yourfile.txt | awk -F " " '{if ($1<1000) print $1;else print $2 }' > result.txt
```

**Input**
*yourfile.txt* contains:

> 29 DEADLETTER
> 123 SU
> 1234 SR
> 100089 SM
> 1278969 DR

**Output**
*result.txt* looks like this:

> 29
> 123
> SR
> SM
> DR